# Why can't I set a task dependency on preReleaseBuild task, but preBuild task works?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How can I set a dependency on these two tasks? `preReleaseBuild` and `preDebugBuild`

I want to do the following:

```
preReleaseBuild.dependsOn switchToRelease
preDebugBuild.dependsOn switchToDebug
```

But I get this error:

```
Error:(251, 0) Could not find property 'preReleaseBuild' on project ':app'.
```

Those two tasks clearly exist, because I see them when I run `gradle assembleRelease`

```
Zaks-MBP:androidapp zak$ gradle assembleRelease
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
:analytics:compileJava
:app:gce2retrofit-release
:feed:compileJava
:gcm:compileJava
:backend:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:gce2retrofit-release UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to use `afterEvaluate`

```
afterEvaluate {
    preReleaseBuild.dependsOn switchToRelease
    preDebugBuild.dependsOn switchToDebug
}
```

Comment: In your code example "afterEvalutate" is misspelled. It should be "afterEvaluate"